# Trying to Update Record in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to implement a `PATCH` route where if the path is `/{userid}/{attribute}`, the attribute of that user will be changed to the specified attribute. I currently have:

```
Route::patch('/{userId}/{band}', function($userId, $band){

     $user = DB::table('users')->find($userId);
     $user->favorite_band = $band;
     $user->save();

     return $user;
});
```

This is not working. I get an error along the lines of

```
(1/1) TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)
```

I'm very new to `Laravel` and not sure how to do this. This is all being done in the `web.php` routes file. I haven't used a `Controller` yet.

Comment: add `csrf_token()` in your form

Comment: @aldrin27 Obviously OP is implementing a RESTful API so it's very unlike to have a form...

Comment: I am just working on the backend at the moment. I have an index view properly giving me json of all users, a show view giving me json of one user. That's where I'm at.

Comment: I think you should use controller so that you have well structure of code

Comment: Just FYI, you can use something like [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding) so your route signature would look like this: `Route::patch('/{user}/{band}', function(App\User $user, $band){...`, and you dont have to "manually" search for given userID. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection by default.

You need to pass along the CSRF token to the AJAX request:

Store the token in `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Assuming you are using jQuery, add the token to all request headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: I am just working on the backend at the moment. I have an index view properly giving me json of all users, a show view giving me json of one user. That's where I'm at.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5, insert the csrf token in the form field.

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In VerifyCsrfToken.php file inside App\Http\Middleware folder update it as follows

```
 protected $except = [
    '*'
];
```

Comment: Verify CSRF token is mainly used for protection if a form is present but as i understand you don't have a view so it shouldn't be a problem.